# opening files in lightbox like google drive

Tags: php, html

i have a cloud storage website, i am currently allowing users to download and share files through my website. I want to add a feature like google drive to open files in a lightbox on the website. The website is made in php. Is there any code for a button which can make the opening of files, images, etc open able like google drive?

Comment: I'd put a LMGTFY link on here, but those aren't allowed.

Comment: hmm, but i require the solution, you can contact me via fb at facebook.com/smitks

Comment: Did you even Google it? Plus, your question does not meet the guidelines on how to ask a question. You should read those.

Comment: yes i have been searching it since a week, hmm its alright i will try to google it again